# how to validate date_select in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my code:

`<%= form_for(:offer,url=>{:controller=>'offers',:action=>'combo'}) do |f|%>`

`<%= f.date_select :startDate %>`

`<%= f.date_select :endDate %>`

I am new in rails.I have two fields to select date.I want the endDate should be greater then the startDate.So, how do i validate this `endDate`.

Comment: Have a look at custom validations in the rails guide

Answer (score 0):

In the modal add this line:-

```
validate :end_date_greater_than_start_date

def end_date_greater_than_start_date
  if !endDate.blank? and endDate.to_date < startDate.to_date
    errors.add(:endDate, "should be greater than start date")
  end
end
```

Comment: it's not working, is there anything i have to add in view page

Answer (score 0):

Is not working because you gave fields a non-standard name. Please avoid using camelCase and refactor like this:

```
<%= f.date_field :start_date %>

<%= f.date_field :end_date %>
```

and

```
validate :end_date_greater_than_start_date

def end_date_greater_than_start_date
    if start_date && end_date && start_date > end_date
      errors.add(:to_date, "YOUR ERROR MESSAGE")
    end
end
```